# converting xcode codebase to framework

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application on the App Store which I want to add SiriKit to, I researched and I saw that I have to add use framework to set logic of the main application and the siri Intent.

How do I convert my ready made API codes to framework Xcode.

I am new to this aspect of production

Comment: Takes a look at this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/600-sirikit-tutorial-for-ios

Comment: It is a great tutorial but they didn't state how they made the framework

Comment: I am followed the tutorial till it was time to implement my own Logic and I got confused

Answer (score 0):

You don't **have** to use a framework to share code, it's recommended though.

What you can do, if you only have a small number of files shared across the targets is select the files containing the shared code and tick the siri target in the Target membership section for each file. Then the code for the network operations will be available to both the app and the Siri target.

The Ray Wenderlich site also has a couple of [tutorials on creating frameworks](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios) if that is the way you want to go

Comment: Thanks. could I just open the app directly? to a particular ViewController

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you mean? 'The App' is the main app, Adding Siri to it is an app extension. so you literally just add the extension, select the files you need to use from the app and tick the siri box too in the target membership and then the extension will be compiled with those files too. or you could put the shared code in a framework and share it to both the app and the extension. this way is usually better if its a big project or there will be many extensions, or theres lots of shared code.